# Send file as attachment using same method as shell context menu "send as e-mail"

Tags: email, command-line, send, windows-shell

MS outlook uses e.g. following line in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mailto\shell\open\command:
"C:\PROGRA~2\MIF5BA~1\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE" -c IPM.Note /m "%1"

When sending a file using the context menu "send to >> E-Mail", the outlook.exe gets a call like
"C:\PROGRA~2\MIF5BA~1\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE" -Embedding

How? Is the explorer shell using another send-to-mechanism? Several forum articals advice to use the above registry key...

My purpose is to use the same method as windows/explorer/shell does from my own application (BTW: no, the regular SMTP send methods from System.Net & Co. can't be used since they require information about SMTP server address, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the system SendTo folder you'll find a shortcut which is responsible for adding this item to the Send To menu. When selected Explorer binds to the folder, obtains an IDropTarget interface for the shortcut using IShellFolder::GetUIObject and simulates a drop of the selected files to the shortcut.